# Error connecting to a defined route in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I've defined my route in api.php but when I try to connect this route through postman it throws the following error.

```
The specified URL cannot be found
```

Here is my route in api.php.

```
Route::put("certification/{certification-id}/applications/{application}/apply",'MyController@update');
```

I've checked the ip address and other path variables. Everything is fine but still getting this error.

Comment: Is it route set to accept all request methods or just specific? I.E. any, post, get? Also, have you tried to clear the route cache? `php artisan route:clear`. Are the other paths accessible via postman? Do you use homestead or your host OS for dev and environment setup?

Comment: Have to mark the method as put in postman?

Comment: yes I did and if it was the wrong method selection issue it should say method not allowed exception rather it is giving not connection issue.

Comment: I ran this command and still having the same issue @niklaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the `-` to a `_` in `{certification-id}`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

> Route parameters are always encased within {} braces and should consist of alphabetic characters, and may not contain a - character. Instead of using the - character, use an underscore (_). Route parameters are injected into route callbacks / controllers based on their order - the names of the callback / controller arguments do not matter.

Comment: Thanks, I've already found its solution but I am leaving this question and its answer to help others. :)

Comment: Doesn't look like you've marked my answer as having answered the question.

Comment: May be system takes some time please wait for a while. I've up voted the answer.

Comment: It's not the upvote - it's the Green Checkmark below that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 0):

You should check the port where the localhost is configured to run. If you are using apache, you can check this in httpd.conf file near line number 50.

And make sure you have used `php artisan serve` as written in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation).